# Правильный перенос слов - малиновка, выставка, пословица

Tags: перенос

Правильный перенос слов - малиновка, выставка, пословица???

Comment: Надо уметь формулировать вопрос, и уж совсем лишнее ставить по несколько "?" подряд.

Comment: Не говоря уже о том, что можно было бы попытаться хоть как-нибудь выполнить это домашнее задание, хоть частично, хотя бы для одного из слов...

Comment: Олеся, в чем сложность?

Answer (score 2):

> Правильный перенос слов...

См. [ПРАВИЛА ПЕРЕНОСА](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97).

Особое внимание обратите на этот параграф:

> **§ 217.** Группа неодинаковых согласных букв в середине слова, входящих в корень или образующих стык корня и суффикса, может быть
>   разбита переносом любым образом, напр.: ***се-стра, сес-тра*** и
>   ***сест-ра; це-нтральный, цен-тральный*** и ***цент-ральный; ро-ждение*** и ***рож-дение; де-тство, дет-ство, детс-тво*** и
>   ***детст-во; шу-мный*** и ***шум-ный.***
>
> Если же в группе согласных часть принадлежит приставке или если вся
>   группа начинает вторую часть приставочного слова, предпочтительно
>   учитывать членение слова на значимые части. Предпочтительные переносы:
>   ***под-бить, под-бросить, при-слать, от-странить.*** Допустимые переносы: ***по-дбить, подб-росить; прис-лать; отс-транить и
>   отст-ранить.***

Comment: :-) цент-р**о**льный - опечатка в оригинале, к сожалению.

Comment: Спасибо! Исправил. В бумажном-то справочнике написано правильно, а в его электронной версии, к сожалению, это не единственная опечатка.

Answer (score 1):

В приведённых словах желательно не отрывать буквы от корня и суффикса:

[***ма-ли-нов-ка***](http://slovonline.ru/slovar_el_fonetic/b-13/id-61156/malinovka.html), ***вы-став-ка***, ***по-сло-ви-ца***,

другие переносы (по слогам) будут попадать в разряд допустимых, но нежелательных.